# Angular 4 GET 403 response

Tags: django, angular, api, get, authorization

I write an app in Angular 4 that calls a REST API (DJANGO).
The code is as followed:

```
export class ForecastUnitService {

private path = 'forecastunit/';
private options;
constructor (private http: Http, private c:CentralService) {
this.options=this.c.createOptions();
}

getForecastUnits(): Observable<ForecastUnit[]> {
return this.http.get(this.c.createURL(this.path),this.options)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
...
}
```

I add options that contains an authorization header, but still I get
a 403 forbidden. However when I try the call with cUrl or Postman or in swagger, with the same token I get results.
So first tought, the headers aren't correct but when I log options I get:

```
{"method":null,"headers":{"Authorization":["**Correct Token**"],"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"body":null,"url":null,"withCredentials":null,"responseType":null}
```

So that is not the problem, when I look in the response from Chrome I see the following:

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

So again no credentials, but I really passed them, what is going wrong?

Comment: whats the format of your passed token ?

Comment: Basic 64, i guess

Comment: want to know the example format of token you are passing in Authorization

Comment: I pass "Basic " + code in upper and lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's `http` module changes all header names to lowercase. This might be an issue because some API services aren't following the spec and their header checks are case-sensitive when these should be case-insensitive.

Check the configuration of your API.

I assume that your `CentralService` creates valid options.

```
interface RequestOptionsArgs { 
  url: string|null
  method: string|RequestMethod|null
  search: string|URLSearchParams|{[key: string]: any | any[]}|null
  params: string|URLSearchParams|{[key: string]: any | any[]}|null
  headers: Headers|null
  body: any
  withCredentials: boolean|null
  responseType: ResponseContentType|null
}
```

Headers:

```
class Headers {
  static fromResponseHeaderString(headersString: string): Headers
  constructor(headers?: Headers|{[name: string]: any}|null)
  append(name: string, value: string): void
  delete(name: string): void
  forEach(fn: (values: string[], name: string|undefined, headers: Map<string, string[]>) => void): void
  get(name: string): string|null
  has(name: string): boolean
  keys(): string[]
  set(name: string, value: string|string[]): void
  values(): string[][]
  toJSON(): {[name: string]: any}
  getAll(name: string): string[]|null
  entries()
}
```

Comment: The second codeblock in my question are my RequestOptions, these look correct to me..

Comment: TypeScript should highlight possible errors if everything is properly typed in your service. Just in case check [RequestOptionsArgs](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptionsArgs) in Angular docs.

Comment: How to change header checks to case-insensitive? Or headers not to lowercase in Angular?

Comment: It's by design in Angular. I don't have experience with django so I'm unable to help you regarding the REST framework.

Comment: lowercase, uppercase was indeed the problem

Answer (score -1):

Could you show us the CentralService ?
Also you might want to avoid calling it in the constructor , instead implement OnInit